# same code but different results using(css, css3)

Tags: css

Here is how needed look http://fiddle.jshell.net/2tWb6/27/show/

here is source code http://fiddle.jshell.net/2tWb6/27/

Here is same code but looked different http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8sSh/show/

here is same code source http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8sSh/

where can be the problem? fat points, why is visible :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those points are because you are using an unordered list, you could apply css to that to remove them:

```
ul#download_j {
 list-style: none;
}
```

The problem in your fiddle is that you have a space between the ul and the id of that ul. remove that and then it's fine.

Edit:Putting a space between ul and #download_j notes that the container with the id download_j is inside the ul.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `list-style:none;` to your LI, not just your UL

Answer (score 1):

In the example with Bullets, in left column of JSFiddle, under "fiddle Option" is not checked "Normalized CSS" :-)

This is the reason of different behaviour with the (apparently) the same code.

Answer (score 1):

`<ul id="download_j">` will not be selected by `#download_j ul`. It's looking for a `ul` inside `#download_j`.

Change the selector to `ul#download_j` and it'll all be OK.